# Cloudflare SSL Page rules

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare

I am trying to create a few page rules on Cloudflare, that would always force any url to use https:// instead of http://.

I have tried various solutions, but I can't seem to get it right. I either end up with an infinite loop or http:// usage. So I was hoping that somebody could point me in the right direction.

What I want is for all the following Url's to be redirected to use https://:

- example.com
- app.example.com
- user.app.example.com
- www.example.com
- example.com/test
- app.example.com/test
- user.app.example.com/test
- www.example.com/test

I have tried all of the following rules:

1. `*.example.com/* Should forward to https://$1.example.com/$2`
2. `example.com/* Should forward to https://example.com/$2`
3. `*example.com/* Should forward to https://$1example.com/$2`
4. `http://*example.com/* Should always use HTTPS`

Using #1 and #2 together resulted in an infinite redirect loop. So did #3. Number 4 works for 'example.com', but does nothing when I try to access 'app.example.com',

Could anybody please help me fix these page rules?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get by with just a page rule for:

`http://*example.com/*` and "+ A Setting" for "Always Use HTTPS"

You can see a walkthrough in this video:

https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/harden-security/

Answer (score 2):

You're probably infinitely redirecting because you're not explicitly stating "http://" as part of your pattern.

You need 2x CloudFlare Page Rules (combination of Pattern+Rule):

Page Rule 1:

Pattern syntax:

```
http://example.com/*
```

Rule:

*"Always use https"* turn this to ON

Page Rule 2:

Pattern syntax:

```
http://*.example.com/*
```

Rule:

*"Always use https"* turn this to ON

This will pass slugs and params too i.e.

http://example.com/404?somevar=lala

Will redirect to

https://example.com/404?somevar=lala

However you should be aware in addition that:

- This will affect ALL possible subdomains not just your explicit list
- CloudFlare does not support second tier subdomains foo.bar.example.com

Answer (score 0):

The following Page Rule patterns worked for me:

`http://example.com/`

`http://example.com/*`

`http://*.example.com/`

`http://*.example.com/*`

Always uses https: ON

(You have to use both `/` and `/*` to cover the root and any other paths.)

https://www.cloudflare.com/a/page-rules